# Asp.net mvc 3: how to use partialviews in a 1 to many relationship?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking for a article which describes how to construct a 1 to many relationship in asp.net mvc 3. My though is to use partial views but how can I loop through them? How do i setup my page ie master detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers, Views and PartialViews already encumber a one-to-many relationship style.

One view (or partial view) can be returned by many controllers. Many partial views can be rendered by a single View etc etc.

What specific problem are you aiming to solve?

Comment: I have one entity on a Detail page which can have multiple files to be uploaded. So how can I setup the page to edit the main entity details but also the files which can be more than 1. The partial view contains an file upload.

Comment: Store your file upload UI in an editor template. You can learn about these with a quick Google. Or even better, just use one file upload, attach the file as needed and then allow the user to use the same upload UI for the next. The same as Google deals with email attachments.,